# How to get Top 5 ordered products details of specific Categories in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

I want to get Top 5 ordered products details of specific Categories in Magento 2. How Can I do that?

Here is My Code:

```
$cateinstance = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$cateid = 3; 
$productCount=5;
$storeId =1;

$allcategoryproduct = $cateinstance->create()->load($cateid)->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
->setPageSize($productCount)->setStoreId($storeId)->addStoreFilter($storeId);
$allcategoryproduct_count=$allcategoryproduct->getSize();
$allcategoryproduct_data=$allcategoryproduct->getData();
```

Here I'm Getting lot of information about products. But I want only the Product IDs in a array.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want the product ID there is no need to select all the attributes, which you are doing with `->addAttributeToSelect('*')` so you can remove that call.
Also, all collections extend `\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection` so you can use the `getAllIds()` function instead of `getData()`.